# How to remove Amazon skill at amazon alexa console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I need to remove an alexa skill from amazon alexa console, it had been `Live` months ago. But I cannot find any buttons or function at alexa console to remove it.

It's so strange that an developer cannot remove his developed skill from amazon alexa.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to do it? How long have you waited for Amazon team to remove your skill?

Comment: I did it before. About 2~3 days, Amazon will sent email after removing skill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can check here: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/articles/2749/how-do-i-suppress-my-alexa-skill.html

**Summary:**

Skill suppression means your skill will no longer be available to end users. There are two options for skill suppression:

**Hard Take Down Suppression:** Disables your skill for current users that have it enabled and also makes the skill unavailable for enablement by new users.

**Soft Hidden Suppression:** Skill remains active for current users that have it enabled, but the skill is unavailable for enablement by newer users

To suppress your skill, please sign into your developer account and file a contact us request here that includes the skill name, application id, type of suppression request, and reasoning for suppression:

https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/support/contact/contact-us

The skill, once back in 'development' in the developer portal, can be resubmitted at a later point with or without changes.